# How to force building a project with a build-machine-unfriendly Platform Toolset (VS2013)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I know of such a problem recently:

With Visual Studio 2013 installed on Windows 7(not Win8), creating a default MFC app, start building, I'll get error message immediately:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: MFCApplication1, Configuration: Debug
>   Win32 ------
>
> 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(355,5):
>   warning MSB8003: Could not find **WindowsSDKDir** variable from the
>   registry.  **TargetFrameworkVersion** or **PlatformToolset** may be set to an
>   invalid version number.
>
> 1>  stdafx.cpp
>
> 1>c:\users\chj\u8vs2013\mfcapplication1\targetver.h(8): fatal error
>   C1083: Cannot open include file: **'SDKDDKVer.h':** No such file or
>   directory
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

A quick solution is to open the project property, change the Platform Toolset from **v120** to **v120_xp** .

[image]

It seems that, VS2013(or MSBuild behind the scene, not sure which) checks your Toolset's target platform against your building machine(Win7 in this case), and if the Toolset is for a higher Windows version, it rudely quits.

So my question is: How can I force VS2013(or MSBuild) to build with Toolset **v120** even if my building machine is a Windows 7 -- that is, I don't care if the resulting EXE can be run on Win7, I just want to produce the same EXE as it is built inside a Win8 machine, just like cross compiling -- in order to -- for example, send it to remote debugging on a Windows 8 host .

Comment: Did you install the Windows 8 SDK on the Windows 7 machine? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx

Comment: Wow, you are right. Installing Windows 8.1 SDK solve the problem. Please write it as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the Windows 8 SDK on the Windows 7 build agent machines.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx